# Creating records in a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `on: create` validation in my Rails model. In that validation, I create an instance of a `TransactionRecord` model.

However, the `TransactionRecord` is only persisted when the parent model (the one that the validation is run on) is created, which seems strange.

Within the validation, the TransactionRecord object responds positively to `.persisted?`. However, if the validation fails, the `TransactionRecord` object disappears.

I guess it's an ActiveRecord feature that all db transactions that occur in a validation get rolled back if the "parent" doesn't get saved or the validation fails.

How can I ensure that the `TransactionRecord` model gets created regardless of the result of the validation?

## ps

I'm aware that validations aren't the ideal place to create most types of objects.

## edit

Issue resolved, but I'm still interested in a solution to this problem if there is one.

Comment: If you move the "create TransactionRecord" to a "before_validate" method, perhaps it will be persisted? I mean perhaps "before validation" is not wrapped in a db-transaction, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Validations are not a good place to create other ActiveRecord objects.

Try to move the `TransactionRecord` creation to a `before_create` callback.

Just keep in mind that these records might be created even if the object does not pass validation and not persisted.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't move it to a before_create in this case. Yes, I want the record to be persisted regardless of what happens.

Comment: What prevents you from moving it to before_create?

Comment: A third-party API call is made in the validation (like it or not), and the response needs to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TransactionRecord 

validate :persisted, :before => :create

private
  def persisted
    if self.field_name.value?
      errors.add(:field_name, 'is created.')
    end
  end
end
```